# php-pear is not working after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: upgrade, php, 14.04

After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 php-pear is failing to install any packages.

```
sudo pear install --alldeps --force pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
downloading PHPUnit-4.0.17.tgz ...
Starting to download PHPUnit-4.0.17.tgz (509,430 bytes)
......................................................................................................done: 509,430 bytes
could not extract the package.xml file from "/build/buildd/php5-5.5.9+dfsg/pear-build-download/PHPUnit-4.0.17.tgz"
Download of "phpunit/PHPUnit" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "phpunit/PHPUnit"
Download failed
install failed
The packages are being downloaded but can't extract.
```

I've tried this solution, http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/pear-php-5.5.htm
But still getting the same problem.

Has anyone else encountered this? Do I need to downgrade to php5.4? If so, how?.

Update: Thanks for the quick responses. Karels answer solved my problem. Just for completeness the proper way to installing via pear no longer works.
The steps to install from a phar file are documented at: http://phpunit.de/getting-started.html

Also it is no longer necessary include/require
PHPunit/Runner.php and Autoload etc.

Again. Thanks for the help

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/1310552). I am afraid that problems caused by bugs are [off topic here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/226/are-bug-reports-suitable-for-this-site).

Comment: /usr/share/php/Archive/Tar.php can't open tgz files because line 734 is returning "false" when checking for gzopen.

Google has a 5 year old bug (still open) that may be related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/451405

The solution is to find and replace the following in Tar.php:

* Replace 'gzopen' with 'gzopen64'

* Replace 'gzseek' with 'gzseek64' 

* Replace 'gztell' with 'gztell64'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to obtain PHPUnit is to download a PHP Archive (PHAR) that has all required (as well as some optional) dependencies of PHPUnit bundled in a single file.

Open the terminal and type:

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar  # download the PHP Archive (PHAR) file  
chmod +x phpunit.phar  
sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

There are many different versions of phpunit.phar at https://phar.phpunit.de/. If you use the first command, it will select and download the latest version of phpunit.phar.

Comment: Thank you karel..I thiink the last line should be sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit. But that solved my problem

Comment: +1 Tried all answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536668/how-do-i-correctly-install-phpunit-with-pear at first, but your answer solved it for me.